# Local apt repository returns 404 on 'Release' files

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, repository, apache-virtualhost

I've setup a local apt repository using reprepro signed with gpg, but apache returns the following error on a update query:

```
"GET /repos/apt/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease HTTP/1.1" 404 474 "-" "Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.4~rc2)"
"GET /repos/apt/debian/dists/stretch/Release HTTP/1.1" 404 472 "-" "Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.4~rc2)"
```

I don't understand why, these two files exist and are both widely readable:

```
$ ll /var/www/repos/apt/debian/dists/stretch/
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 2,1K mar  1 15:12 InRelease
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1,6K mar  1 15:11 Release
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  488 mar  1 15:12 Release.gpg
```

Maybe the error is elsewhere, I include the apache configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/repos/ >
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/repos/apt/*/db/">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/repos/apt/*/conf/">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/repos/apt/*/incoming/">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

source.list:

```
deb http://localhost/repos/apt/debian stretch main
```

Comment: A look at apache's `error_log` might be useful.

Comment: What did you put in `sources.list` /  `/etc/apt`
 ?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz `error.log` doesn't report anything useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under jessie, the default Apache `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/html`. You'll have to relocate your directories, or create appropriate symlinks, or add the necessary `Alias` declarations to your Apache config.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Ferenc, I've discovered that `default.conf` sets `/var/www/html` as DocumentRoot. Thus, modifying my conf files according to this option I've solved.